# Bootstrap Switch appearing twice in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/ in a Rails 3.2 app that uses Bootstrap 3.

I've added a simple switch like this:

```
<div class="make-switch switch-large">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
</div>
```

It appears as expected when I run the web app on a local server:

[image: How it looks on localhost]

but two switches instead of one appear when I run the web app on Heroku:

[image: How it looks on Heroku]

The html, as shown by Chrome developers tool, is - respectively:

- Local:

[image: local]

- Heroku:

[image: Heroku]

What should I look for to sort out this bug?

Answer (score 2):

In the coffeescript file

```
jQuery ->
  $('input:checkbox').bootstrapSwitch()
```

Comment: i had the same problem, and this, sir, has helped. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap-switch.js was being loaded twice - I checked this by logging from within that js file

It took a while to understand why it was being loaded twice. 
It turned out that in my Heroku app the Rails.env was development instead of production, so my config in production.rb was not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I was using angularjs and directives, the switch was once initialized in directive and another time directly via jquery.

Basically calling this line any number of times produces that much switches:

```js
$('your-checkbox-selector').bootstrapSwitch();
```